# How to get the security ID of the user who is connecting to our Azure Synapse database?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

I'm trying to find out the identities of users who are making a connection to our Synapse database. The following sys object `sys.dm_pdw_exec_connections` provides me a list of connections with the IP address of the client. But the problem is some of our users are using VDI solutions like Citrix and etc. For them, the IP address could be dynamic and hence unreliable in identifying who is connecting to the database.

Hence, I would like to see the security identity of the user who is making a connection towards the database instead of just their client_id. But by using `sys.dm_pdw_exec_connections` I don't get this info.

Is there a way for me to get the security identities for a connection being made to my database?

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is sys.dm_pdw_exec_connections maintains only specific duration logs and in case if pool is puased and resumed all logs are lost.
So you need to configure Log analytics to preserve historical snapshots and my guess is you can get the name details via log analytics

https://bradleyschacht.com/log-analytics-with-dedicated-sql-pools-formerly-sql-dw/